# How I fix an AttributeError with Datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

:I use

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
```

But then, if I use `datetime`:

Example:

```
TimeNow = datetime.datetime.now()
```

It says that:

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

*Can someone help me?*

Comment: It depends on how you import it. `from datetime import datetime; datetime.now()` or `import datetime; datetime.datetime.now()`

Answer (score 0):

`now()` is a function available in the datetime module of the datetime package. Hence to use it you can do either of the two:

```
from datetime import datetime
time_now = datetime.now()
```

or

```
import datetime
time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

In the second case, you need to access the datetime module inside the datetime package and then use the now() function.

Answer (score 0):

You should either `import datetime` and then call:

```
TimeNow = datetime.datetime.now()
```

or you can do:

```
from datetime import datetime
TimeNow = datetime.now()
```